How to obtain an Arris SB8200 modem's HFC MAC address?
I was wondering if there's a way to obtain an Arris SB8200 modem's MAC address (sticker and documentation all lost). Maybe just like you might in an ethernet connection by issuing an arp -a command and looking at the arp table.
Login is required for the Arris SB8200, and a reset sets the password to the SN or HFC address.
The only thing I came across so far is maybe a device like this which would allow me to plug the modem's coax into a converter to a switch or PCs ethernet and running some command or software to find it, if the information isn't lost in this process? Quite expensive however, and probably not worth it. Not sure about the 2nd one.

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B088KVYZGK


https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C5RTRTHG




What is the general convention for Arris modems? Are they the kind which uses consecutive MACs for each port (e.g. :a4 for the LAN interface, :a5 for the WAN interface) like some other manufacturers do, or are they the kind that uses completely different MACs for both?

From what I read, factory reset sets the password to either "password" or the last 8 digits of the serial number, not the MAC address. Did you try those two? Is the serial number really not printed on the bottom? Have you tried contacting Arris? Is the device registered on the Arris warranty system? Have you tried contacting Arris? Maybe they can get you the serial number from the Ethernet MAC (though that would be a security issue).

If there is no rate limiting, you could probably brute force an 8-digit numeric password in a few days.

Have you still got the box it came in? Sometimes the MAC address, and so on, will be on a sticker on that.

I tried contacting arris and they basically said im out of luck and cant do anything, maybe they mentioned ISPs helping but they dont help. I never brought up the idea of using the ethernet MAC to try to get further with arris. I bought it used and the box it came in is not the same product. the web portal is rate limited. Ive tried many username/password combinations on the web.

Called arris again to see if an ethernet MAC address would allow me to obtain any identifying(SN) information on the device. Nope. Needed phone/email/name/SN/etc.

Those adapters won't work with a DOCSIS modem. Obtaining a headend unit (CMTS) isn't feasible, most likely.
Your best bet is to run a packet capture on the Ethernet end and extract the source MAC address from incoming frames. If that doesn't match the MAC address on the DOCSIS side then you're out of luck.

Caution
If resetting the modem causes something other than what's documented on page 15 as described below, then the ISP has altered the firmware. If the firmware has been altered the ISP will have a record of the MAC address, and username required to log in.
Find the Appropriate Documentation
The OP clearly knows this is an Arris Branded SurfBoard 8200. On that page is a Support Link.  The OP doesn't need a Packet Capture or anything else, just the proper Instruction Manual - The SB8200 User Guide.
Finding The MAC Address
After following the Login procedure clearly stated on page 15, Click the Address Button in the Navigation row as shown on the ARRIS Consumer Care FAQ for the SB8200 under Locating the MAC Address Using the Web Interface.
Detailed Instructions
Factory Resetting the modem is the best bet now that the documentation has been located, so that the Login process located on the elusive page 15 works as intended.  Even with the Lost Sticker everything you need is located in the web interface.  If the modem is currently connected to the internet:

Download the above documentation
Unscrew the incoming cable from the Cable company
If any other router is connected to a LAN port disconnect it.
Unplug the Power and Hold in the Reset Switch for 1 to two minutes (This is a cold Factory Reset)

A hot Factory Reset is power plugged in, and hold reset for 30 seconds.
Since we want to make sure the modem replicates page 15, a cold reset is required.


Plug your PC's ethernet port into the LAN 1 port.  Do not screw in the coax cable
Power up the modem, and follow the directions on page 15.

Important
This modem is a brick modem, it has no bridge mode. As such the Wireless Router needs to be plugged into LAN Port One before screwing the co-ax cable into the back, but after powering on both the modem and the router.
The 192.168.100.1 page is only the modem setup page and nothing else.

I dont think this is going to work. i already tried using password as the password to get into the web portal. So next I held the reset button down for 10-15 seconds until the lights flashed when it was directly connected to my pc-ethernet and power- and tried several different combinations. And since the manual mentions the password is the SN and the SN is on the sticker i don't have, im still locked out from obtaining any information.

That's not what I found on Page 15 in the link above. Try admin for the username and password for the password.  Do I need to upload a screenshot for you of page 15?  Are you running into the Note I now see? If that's the case, contact your ISP  They should have a record of the Serial Number
